# Two views for Registration In Devise - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm in a confusing situation . I am using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication in my application . And i want two different views for my Registration process . In my views i put them both in `devise/Registration` folder

```
1-business.html.erb
2-new.html.erb
```

But i got no way to access that 'business' file view . I have only one model `User` and i need these two views due to a flag in the `user table` . I can not also redriect according to their `falgs` like `current_user.myflag` because i need to do it even before registration .I checked some links too but they are different from my options -

Updated:
I have tried overriding Devise Registration controller like below but that also didn't helped me .

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def business
    end
end
```

As the business method is empty - It didn't gave the devise the good idea about resource name and type etc . I also tried

```
def business
 resource = User.new
end
```

But never worked
Any help will be greatly apprecaited . thanks

Comment: Do you update your routes file?

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay problem was not in routes file because controller was app was going into `def business` but it was not working

Comment: Is there any error message you faced.

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay can you plz make a code sample for child registration class with the business method in it - error messages were `undefine resource` and `undefined devise_error_message!`

Comment: basically, you wanted to have same registration but  you want to place `business.html.erb` in a different views? is that what you want to do?

Comment: @Marv-C yes dear , layout is also different somehow

Comment: ill write up my suggestion and see if it works for you.

Comment: @Marv-C thanks dear :) i appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe we had the same problem when i wanted to put devise registration to other views and i gotten the same problem. `undefined resources or nil` to fix this issue you need to `initialize the resource` somehow. One way is to initialize resource in the `helpers/application_helpers:` so you can call it to any views. note: `resource here is user`

```
 def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

In the Overriding controller

```
class CustomSessionController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 include ApplicationHelper
 def business
 end
end
```

In Route.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "custom_session" }

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/business-signup" =>"custom_session#business"
end
```

I hope it helps you solve your problem.

Comment: dear where would i place my `def business;`

Comment: i updated your answer with some more key points which solved it . accepting your post as answer as you make me think again about that .and ofcourse was a big hit :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to Override your devise/registration controller with your business method and define routes for same

You can use below link for reference

https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/2343176